# Jquery slider not stoping when pause /play is clicked

Tags: jquery, slider, pause

I am coding a simple jquery slider, currently I cant get it to start when I click the play/pause button,  am using an if and a stop = false state to start the slider but cant get it to work, the code is fairly simple but I am a bit of a newbie in js.

The swapslides function does its job, its the condition checker where the code breaks.

You can take a look at the code here:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var stop = true;

    

    $('.play').click(function(){
  if (stop == true) {
        stop = false;
  alert(stop);
        }
        else {
        stop = true;
  alert(stop);
        }
    });
 
 if(stop == false){
 setInterval(swapSlides, 3000);
 }
 
 
    function swapSlides(){
 var cs = $('div.currentslide:first');
 var ns = cs.next();
 if(ns.hasClass('mySlides1')){
 cs.removeClass('currentslide');
 ns.addClass('currentslide');
    }
 else{
 ns = $('#polaroid1').children('div.mySlides1:first');
 cs.removeClass('currentslide');
 ns.addClass('currentslide');
 }
 }
 
});
</script>
```

```css
.play{
 position:absolute; 
 left:5px; 
 bottom:5px; 
 cursor:pointer; 
 z-index:10000;
}

.polaroid1{
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
 transform: rotate(-8deg); 
 margin-bottom:30px; 
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0); 
 text-align:right; 
 padding-top:10px; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 padding-left:10px; 
 padding-bottom:15px; 
 top:15px; 
 left:25px; 
 position:relative;
}

.photo1{
 width:100%;  
 height:85%; 
 position:relative;
 padding:5px;
}

.date1{
 margin:0; 
 padding-right:10px; 
 font-family: 'Covered By Your Grace', cursive; 
 transform: rotate(-5deg);
 font-size:28px;
}

.mySlides1{
 display:none;
 width:380px; 
 height:320px; 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0px; 
 left:0px;
}

.currentslide{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="polaroid1" class="polaroid1">
  <img class="play" src="images/heart.png">
  <div class="mySlides1 fade currentslide">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0028.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170812_181516.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">12-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_112958.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/IMG-20170610-WA0017.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">10-06-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170819_194526.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170811_182103.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">11-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170522_124602.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170419_020725.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">19-04-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170520_115819.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">20-05-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170822_011703.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">22-08-2017</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides1 fade">
    <img class="photo1" src="images/20170705_184344.jpg">
    <h3 class="date1">05-07-2017</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) you are not stoping the interval

add:

```
var slideInterval;
```

and change:

```
$('.play').click(function(){
    if (stop == true) {
    stop = false;
    alert(stop);
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
    }
    else {
    stop = true;
    alert(stop);
    slideInterval = setInterval(swapSlides, 3000);
    }
});
```

and is not needed:

```
if(stop == false){
   setInterval(swapSlides, 3000);
}
```